# ARANGO DB relation between 2 collections

Tags: arangodb

I need to know how to get the master child relations in arangoDB.
I have a following document collection called user given below

```
{
  "firstName": "dasdsa",
  "lastName": "Deshpande",
  "emailAddress": "Abc@GAURAV.CO.IN",
  "password": "aA@1234",
  "applicationId": [
    180031,
    180091
  ],
  "isActiveUser": "false",
  "isAdminUser": "false",
     }
```

and second document collection named application

```
 {
  "id":"180031",
  "applicationName": "firstApp",
  "description": "first app description"
}

 {
      "id":"180091
  ",
      "applicationName": "secondApp",
      "description": "first app description"
    }
```

I want to retrieve application name based  on the application id that is been tagged to the user. In this case I want to retrieve firstApp and secondApp.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned how you want to do that, so I will assume AQL.

First off, there is something wrong with your data model. Your user document stores an array of **numbers** as `applicationId` attribute, but the application documents have an `id` attribute which is a **string**. The data types should match, otherwise you can't join them without type casting (which may lead to indexes not being utilized).

Secondly, I wonder why you chose to store the application ID as `id` attribute instead of the `_key` attribute, which is indexed by default (primary index). I assume every application ID occurs only once in the entire collection and won't change later? If so, consider to store the application ID as string in the `_key` attribute. Otherwise create an appropriate index for the `id` attribute.

To the actual query: there are two main approaches to join the collections, either using the `DOCUMENT()` function to resolve the IDs or using an additional FOR loop with a FILTER. Note however that you need to store the application ID as document `_key` in order to be able to look up the applications using the first approach with `DOCUMENT()`. The nested FOR loop approach is more flexible and allow you to look up documents using any attribute, including ones that aren't indexed (but this may result in slow performance).

```
FOR u IN user
  FILTER u.emailAddress == "Abc@GAURAV.CO.IN"
  RETURN { user: u, applications: DOCUMENT("application", u.applicationId) }
```

I'm using a FILTER on the email address here to select a user document. This could also be on a different attribute or using `LET u = DOCUMENT("user/<document-key>")`. The first argument to the `DOCUMENT()` function is the target collection name, and the second argument is the array of document `_keys` (application IDs).

If you want to keep the application IDs stored in the `id` attribute, you can use this query:

```
FOR u IN user
  FILTER u.emailAddress == "Abc@GAURAV.CO.IN"
  LET applications = (FOR a IN application
    FILTER a.id IN u.applicationId
    RETURN a
  )
  RETURN { user: u, applications }
```

The same query would also work if you stored the IDs as document keys, simply replace the condition with `FILTER a._key IN u.applicationId`. But since you can use the [DOCUMENT() function](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-miscellaneous.html#document) in this scenario, I would rather use that as it's simpler.

This is well described in the AQL tutorial BTW:
https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/tutorial-join.html